# How to access mysql database server via vpn tunnel with a GUI client

Tags: phpmyadmin, database-connection, mysql-workbench, vpn

I want to use a GUI mySQL client to connect a database server 10.0.0.5 which is reachable via a vpn distant server vpn.my_vpn_server.com.
I can do it with my console

```
:~$ ssh my_user@vpn.my_vpn_server.com
:~$ Enter passphrase for key : xxxxxxxx
:~$ mysql -h 10.0.0.5 -u db_user -ppwd
```

but I want a GUI (phpmyadmin or mySqlworkbench ).
Anyhelp ?

Comment: What does this have to do with sql-server?

Comment: sql server distant connection with GUI client. so it is all about sql server

Comment: Not sure I follow. You want to use the mysql GUI to connect to a sql server database?

Comment: yes but this DB is reacheable via vpn server, not directly, so I should connect via ssh to vpn.my_vpn_server.com then to 10.0.0.5

Comment: Can you even open a sql server database from the mysql gui? You can't do that the other way around.

Comment: Just so you are aware, sql-server is a DBMS from Microsoft which is NOT the same thing as mysql. Hence my confusion.

Comment: ah sorry for that, I forgot about this :)

Answer (score 5):

Finally I made it, MySQL workbench can do it.
[image]